# Changing the content of Data attribute for Path markup syntax?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, path, markup

```
<Path x:Name="Part" Fill="Red" Data="M0,0 L0,-100 A100,100 0 0 1 100,0 z" Margin="261,197,-261,-197" />
```

How can I access respective change all the Data in C# Code?
I'm able to change the color etc. but I'm not able to access M, L A etc.

```
SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
Part.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
```

Comment: Dependending on what you are actually doing, it might be simpler to create and modify a Geometry in code behind, instead of copying and modifying one that was parsed from XAML.

Comment: Actually I'm new to this and I thought it would have been easier to start with XAML so I can visually figure out how to do it and implement it afterwards code it C#.

Comment: Maybe I should explain better what I try to do. I want to create a Gauge and I'm trying to find a way to build the segments of the circle (not the needle). Like here -> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sheldonyss/ng2-gauge-with-color-band/master/screenshoots/2017-08-11_12-56-10.gif And I want to have it dynamic, so I can decide how many segments I would like to have.

Answer (score 1):

When parsed from XAML, the `Data` property holds an immutable [`StreamGeometry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.streamgeometry?view=netframework-4.8), which

> Defines a geometric shape, described using a StreamGeometryContext. This geometry is light-weight alternative to PathGeometry: it does not support data binding, animation, or modification.

You may however create a `PathGeometry` copy of the current Data, modify it and pass it back to the Data property.

In the code below, the copy is only created when `Data` does not already contain a modifiable PathGeometry, so when you call it multiple times, only a single copy will be created.

```
if (!(Part.Data is PathGeometry path) || path.IsFrozen)
{
    path = PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(Part.Data);
}

foreach (var figure in path.Figures)
{
    foreach (var segment in figure.Segments)
    {
        if (segment is ArcSegment arc)
        {
            arc.Point = new Point(0, 100);
        }
        //else if ...
    }
}

Part.Data = path;
```

See [Path Geometries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/geometry-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#path-geometries) for details of all the different segment types.

Comment: That's a nice answer !

Comment: Thanks I will try this out.  I have also seen following but it doesn't work so far or it doesn't give me an output.             

Path p = new Path();
p.Fill = Brushes.Black;
p.Data = Geometry.Parse("M0,0 L0,-100 A100,100 0 0 1 100,0 z");

Comment: You may add a RotateTransform member to your class and set the end point of the ArcSegment by `arc.Point = rotation.Transform(new Point(0, -100))`. If the angle becomes greater than 180° you would also have to set `arc.IsLargeArc = true`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Clemens and @aybe correctly wrote when parsing a Geometry from a string, a StreamGeometry instance is created.
But you can set your own Geometry instead of a string, and then you will have access to each of its elements.
Any of these segments can be changed, animated, deleted, added.

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1">
    <Path x:Name="Part" Fill="Red" Data="M0,0 L0, -100 A100,100 0 0 1 100,0 z" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Path x:Name="PathFullSintacsis" Fill="Red" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry x:Name="PartFullGeometry">
                <PathFigure x:Name="PartFullFigure" StartPoint="0 0" IsClosed="True">
                    <LineSegment x:Name="PartFullLine"  Point="0 -100"/>
                    <ArcSegment x:Name="PartFullArc" Point="100 0" RotationAngle="90" Size="100 100" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</UniformGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks this is a very good idea. But my goal is to actually create everything from C# Code so I can keep it dynamic and I just used the Xaml because I thought it would be faster to try it out there and then code it out. But maybe I can still reach it with your way. I first create all the segments and then I apply it in the code. My goal actually is something like this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sheldonyss/ng2-gauge-with-color-band/master/screenshoots/2017-08-11_12-56-10.gif (without needle). But I would like to have the amount of segments dynamic.

Comment: There are no problems with this.
Or create a string and convert it to Geometry using the [Geometry.Parse(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometry.parse?view=net-5.0) or [GeometryConverter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometryconverter?view=net-5.0).
Or use the derived Geomery classes to create any instance of your own.
Assign the resulting Geometry instance to the Data property.

Comment: "My goal actually is something like this..." - More than one brush cannot be assigned to one Shape.
For each segment with a different color, you need to create a separate Shape instance.
If you supplement the question with all the necessary data to draw the picture you need, I can show you an example of the code to implement it.